# Date time format in vb.net

Tags: sql-server-2005, vb.net-2010

I am using following query to get data from SQL Server 2005 using VB.NET 4.0

```
strSQL = "SELECT EmpNo,
                 Sum(Cast(Substring(OTHours, 0, 3)AS FLOAT)) AS Hour,
                 Sum(Cast(Substring(OtHours, 4, 5)AS FLOAT)) AS Minutes
          FROM   TMSTrans
          WHERE  CONVERT(VARCHAR, datein, 103) >= '01/06/2012'
                 AND CONVERT(VARCHAR, datein, 103) <= '27/06/2012'
          GROUP  BY EmpNo"
```

But incorrect data is returned - I think it's a date range problem. In the table I have a datetime field in which data exists like `01/04/2012 00:00:00`. Can anyone help?

Comment: did you tried to execute that query in sql and it worked?

Comment: it worked but othours not coming on right way. i mean data is verified . there must be a problem from date.

Comment: when i execute this whole table in query analyzer then date comes like 2012-04-01 00:00:00.000. when i give date range with this format, data coming fine. and when i convert date format as above data not coming fine.

Comment: you have to use same date format for both the parameters and table's date. check this link http://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-format-datetime-date-in-sql-server-2005/

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you using `year month day` as the date format in your query. US uses `Month Day Year` as their date format, so if you use `01/06/2012` in your query, the system may recognize the `6 Jan 2012`. Therefore you query is actually getting the date range between `6 January` and `27 June`.

let try this:

```
strSQL = "SELECT EmpNo,
             Sum(Cast(Substring(OTHours, 0, 3)AS FLOAT)) AS Hour,
             Sum(Cast(Substring(OtHours, 4, 5)AS FLOAT)) AS Minutes
      FROM   TMSTrans
      WHERE  CONVERT(VARCHAR, datein, 112) >= '20120601'
             AND CONVERT(VARCHAR, datein, 112) <= '20120627'
      GROUP  BY EmpNo"
```